# How to add an exception for password policy for a user in Windows AD

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

Here is the scenario,

One of our users, needs an exception to password policy (VIP user). How is it possible it AD.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Mind telling the full form of AD

Comment: @Valay_17 Active Directory

Answer (score 0):

Create a Fine Grained Password Policy (FGPP) with a lower precedence than other FGPP's and apply it to the user or group that the user is a member of.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/adac/introduction-to-active-directory-administrative-center-enhancements--level-100-#fine_grained_pswd_policy_mgmt

http://techgenix.com/configuring-fine-grained-password-policies/